# How to change cv2 from python 3.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am installing opencv on macos, and using 
`brew install opencv3 --with-python3`
and it downloaded and installed python 3.7 automatically. But I would like link opencv to python 3.6, so what should I do?

Comment: try : `brew install opencv3 --with-python3.6`

Comment: Did you had python 3.6 installed before or do you expect that the command line install this specific version ?

Comment: I have already installed 3.6 before. And I just want cv2 can be used in python 3.6. Now when installing opencv by brew, it automatically downloaded and linked to python 3.7. How can I change the path or do anything to realize it.

Comment: I tried `brew install opencv3 --with-python3.6` but it said `Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-python3.6 option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: I have already installed 3.6 before. And I just want cv2 can be used in python 3.6. Now when installing opencv by brew, it automatically downloaded and linked to python 3.7. How can I change the path or do anything to realize it. Or can I install python 3.6 specifically when installing opencv? @AIEmerich

Comment: I tried brew install opencv3 --with-python3.6 but it said Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-python3.6 option so it will be ignored! @HarshaB

Answer (score 0):

When brew is done compiling and installing OpenCV3, update path of site-packages directory which contains cv2.so file to Homebrew Python’s site-packages directory. Depending upon the Python version you have (3.6/3.7), these paths would be different.

## For Python 3.6

```
echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.6/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencv3.pth
```

You may want to explore [this link](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/) as well.

Comment: Cause when I installed opencv, it automatically downloaded python 3.7, so there is no python 3.6 folder in /opencv/lib/. Could I just change the folder name? Or how can I choose which version of python when installing opencv?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by linking the brew installed python 3.7 file to my existed python 3.6 file.

Details can be seen from this [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-opencv-3-for-python-on-mac/)!

Just find two paths and do a ln -s command.